# Windows nested folder permissions

Tags: windows, permissions, file-permissions

If I give a user full modify access to folder 'foobar' located in path

foo/bar/foobar

Do I also need to manually give the user read access to foo and again to bar?

Or will the client only receive access to foobar when they manually map directly to /foo/bar/foobar?

Comment: No you can give them `LIST` to only those "parent" folders and then explicit `MODIFY` access to the `/foobar` folder and files within. With `LIST` access this will allow them to see the file names in the parent folders (and traverse) but not open or read the contents of files within those folders.Typically you'd be worried about the access to the file contents within the folders unless the file names are of a concern and contain detail you want to restrict access to but technically this is the answer but it kind of depends on your security needs really.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you need to grant rights to the parent folders as well. The user, that has permissions for 'foobar', can't access it through parent folders 'foo' and 'bar', because the user can't see them.

Although you can share the 'foobar' folder. Then the user can access that folder directly. Other direct access methods should work as well.

Obviously it's possible to do like @Pimp Juice IT recommended, too.

Comment: Being able to see those folders is not a requisite; the subfolder can still be accessed by its full path.

Comment: Then you don't need to grant any more rights to any folders, as you probably might have already figured out.